# Scss compile Error "Expected end of text, found '@' "

Tags: css, sass, less

I tried to compile scss but error below. how i can to solve this

```
@import 'material-kit/variables';
^
Expected end of text, found '@'  (at char 521), (line:16, col:1)
```

Comment: What's the line before this in your SCSS file? Did you forget a semi-colon?

Comment: Looks like some syntax before this wasn't closed. Please include that code in the question.

Comment: every line end with semi-colon

Comment: Post the rest of the file. There isn't enough information to help.

Comment: @devnext - I get the same issue. Works fine when doing via ruby SASS, but not pythons `scss` method?